# What will happen if I move a villager out of his village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a small village with 7 villagers and some of them is green rope villager, as they offer no trades I'm about to move them to somewhere far away from the village then lock them in a house to reduce the village population and make the villagers breed more.

So the question is does it works like that or it will still count that villager as a member of that village?

Comment: Try it? It's a sandbox game, we can't tell you what happens for every possible action.

Comment: Is there any reason not to kill this villager instead?  That should definitely lower the population.

Comment: A few useful wiki's: [Villager](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Villager), [Villager Farming](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Villager_Farming), and [Village Mechanics](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Village_mechanics).

Comment: @Timmy Jim: I want to keep them as a backup also, incase my villagers all die in a siege, I will bring them back to start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be a village there needs to be at least 1 villager and a door.

The Minecraft village zone is a circle that radiates from the center of the village.

The center of the village is the block where the coordinates of all the doors in the village average out. Just make a best guess about the center of your village and you won't be far off.

To calculate how far you'd need to move your villager, count how many blocks the farthest door is from the village center and go a few blocks further to be safe. If the distance to the farthest door is less than 32 blocks, then use 32 blocks as your minimum distance.

You can also dig out a hole beneath the Nitwit (the name for the green-robed villagers) and pour in lava. You will kill him and not make the rest of the villagers aggressive.